# Пиксельный доступ к изображению в OpenCV

Tags: c++, изображения, opencv

Есть матрица OpenCV:

```
cv::Mat m;
```

Нужно, например, пробежаться по ней циклом и вывести значения всех каналов каждого пикселя. В одном проекте (OpenVINO samples, но это не так важно) для этого используется такой цикл:

```
for (size_t c = 0; c < channels; c++) {
    for (size_t h = 0; h < height; h++) {
        for (size_t w = 0; w < width; w++) {
            std::cout << m.at<cv::Vec3b>(h, w)[c];
        }
    }
}
```

Попытка использовать этот кусочек в моём приложении привела к тому, что все изображения оказались битыми. Пришлось разбираться с циклом. И я теперь не могу понять, не содержит ли он ошибку.

Допустим изображение 1-канальное (один из случаев, в котором я безуспешно пытался применить этот цикл). Тогда, казалось бы, все значения пикселей должны лежать последовательно как переменные `unsigned char`, это значит, что разница между адресами соседних пикселей должна быть равна 1, вывожу на экран:

```
std::cout << (void*)&(m.at<cv::Vec3b>(10, 7)[0]) << std::endl;
std::cout << (void*)&(m.at<cv::Vec3b>(10, 8)[0]) << std::endl;
```

и вижу совсем не то:

```
0000017C9F7123D5
0000017C9F7123D8
```

С другой стороны всё правильно, если мы интерпретируем позицию как 3-вектор, то разница адресов должна быть как раз 3 байта (uchar). Но тогда цикл выше некорректно работает для изображений, у которых не 3 канала. Выходит, что у Intel в их примерах ошибка.

Как же на самом деле следует обращаться к пикселям `cv::Mat`? Содержит ли цикл выше ошибку, или это я неправильно его применил?

Answer (score 1):

Для одноканальных изображений (`CV_8UC1`) вместо  `m.at<cv::Vec3b>` должно быть `m.at<uchar>()`, для другой канальности соответственно нужно поменять тип.

Да, каждая строка матрицы лежит последовательно (между строками может быть зазор, обусловленный выравниванием step), это можно использовать при работе на низком уровне - через `ptr()` как указатель на начало всего блока данных или конкретную строку адресовать байтовый массив

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <cstdio>
#include <opencv2/imgcodecs.hpp>

int main(){
    cv::Mat m = cv::imread("img.bmp");
    unsigned size = m.cols * m.rows * m.channels();
    for(unsigned i = 0; i < size; ++i) printf((i+1) % m.channels() ? "%02X " : "%02X\n", m.data[i]);
    return 0;
}
```